# Error en lectura de datos tipo INT con Scanner JAVA

Tags: java, scanner

tengo un problema en la lectura de datos tipo **int** con *'nextInt'* y no sé de qué puede ser. Os dejo el método que me está dando el error; si falta algo o queréis el código completo, podéis pedírmelo. ¿Podríais decirme qué puede ser?

```
static int numero_DNI;
static ArrayList<Integer> DNI = new ArrayList <Integer>();
static boolean comprobar;
protected ArrayList<Integer> ImportarDNI() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    numero_DNI = sc.nextInt();
    DNI.add(numero_DNI);

    if (DNI.size() > 7 && DNI.size()<0) {
        System.err.println("El DNI debe tener los 7 números");
        comprobar = false;
    } else {
        comprobar = true;
    }

    sc.close();
    return DNI;
}
```

Errores:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Personas.Persona.ImportarDNI(Persona.java:30)
at Personas.Persona.main(Persona.java:64)
```

Comment: Pon el error que sale

Comment: prueba a poner `while (sc.hasNextInt() && sc.hasNext())` después de la declaración del escaner hasta antes del `close()`.

Comment: Puedes hacer la siguiente comprobación : `if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Found :" + sc.nextInt());
         }` para saber si entran datos

Comment: Con un else que diga algo si no reconoce los int

Comment: Pro cierto, el ArrayList va a tener un size de 1 siempre, a menos que en el Scanner introduzcas los números separados por espacios, Scanner tomará todos los números que estén juntos como uno solo

Comment: debajo del nextInt pon un sc.nextLine(); y listo

Comment: La comunidad funciona, aceptando la respuesta que te resolvió el problema, marcándola con la palomita que esta justo a lado izquierdo de la respuesta; por favor no agregues textos como **RESUELTA**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer esto. He dejado algunos comentarios:

```
package com.test.victor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImportarDNI();
    }

    private static String numero_DNI;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> DNI = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static boolean comprobar;

    private static final Set<Character> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    static {
        numbers.add('0');
        numbers.add('1');
        numbers.add('2');
        numbers.add('3');
        numbers.add('4');
        numbers.add('5');
        numbers.add('6');
        numbers.add('7');
        numbers.add('8');
        numbers.add('9');
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> ImportarDNI() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // He añadido esta línea para que el usuario introduzca un número
        System.out.println("Introduzca el numero: ");

        numero_DNI = sc.nextLine().trim();

        // No puede sser mayor tue 7 y menor que cero al mismo tiempo: DNI.size() > 7 &&
        // DNI.size() < 0
        // Mejor utilizar la función: checkRightInput(String input)
        if (numero_DNI.length() != 7) {
            System.err.println("El DNI debe tener los 7 números");
            comprobar = false;
            sc.close();
            // Devolvemos la ArrayList<>() vacía
            return new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            if (checkRightInput(numero_DNI)) {
                // Al comprobarlo podemos convertir la String en Integer y agregarlo a DNI
                Integer tested = Integer.valueOf(numero_DNI);
                DNI.add(tested);
                System.out.println("DNI introducido correctamente");
                comprobar = true;
                sc.close();
                return DNI;
            } else {
                comprobar = false;
                sc.close();
                System.out.println("No se han podido introducir los datos");
                // Devolvemos la ArrayList<>() vacía
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }

    }

    private static boolean checkRightInput(String input) {

        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

        for (char c : chars) {
            // Comprobar que cada caracter es un numero entre 0 y 9
            if (!numbers.contains(c)) {
                System.out.println("El caracter '" + c + "' no representa un número");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

He implemantado tu problema de la siguiente manera;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
int numero_DNI;
ArrayList<Integer> DNI = new ArrayList <Integer>();
boolean comprobar;
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<Integer> dnis= new ArrayList<Integer>();
do {

    main m = new main();
    dnis=m.ImportarDNI();
}while(true);




}

public ArrayList<Integer> ImportarDNI() {
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Introduce el DNI");
    numero_DNI = sc.nextInt();
    DNI.add(numero_DNI);

    if (DNI.size() > 7 && DNI.size()<0) {
        System.err.println("El DNI debe tener los 7 números");
        comprobar = false;
    } else {
        comprobar = true;
    }

    return DNI;
}       

}
```

Y no da ningún problema. El problema lo tienes a la hora de cerrar el flujo de entrada de datos, quita esa linea y deja que java lo gestione como crea el conveniente. Otro posible problema que puedes tener es que intestes introducir una letra.. al final de los números, para hacer eso tendrás que emplear `nextLine()` y el ultimo de los errores que puedes tener es que excedas el numero de dígitos permitidos.

Answer (score 0):

Se resuelve mejor pasando un *String* en lugar de *int* y comprobando el número de caracteres.

```
public class LeerNumeros {
    int numero_DNI;
    ArrayList<String> DNI;
    boolean comprobar;


public LeerNumeros() {
    DNI  = new ArrayList <String>();
    comprobar = false;
}


/**
 * Se le inserta un dni y comprueba si la cantidad de caracteres es igual a 9.
 * @param paramdni es el dni para insertar en arraylist DNI.
 * @return
 */
protected ArrayList<String> ImportarDNI(String paramdni) {

    char[] caracteresdni = paramdni.toCharArray();

    while(comprobar==false) {
        if(caracteresdni.length==9) {
            comprobar=true;
            DNI.add(paramdni);
            System.out.println("Dni con nº:"+DNI.toString()+" agregado correctamente");
            return DNI; 
        } else {
            comprobar=false;
            System.err.println("Un dni consta de 8 numeros y una letra (8 caracteres).");
            return DNI; 
        }
    }
    return DNI;
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    LeerNumeros l = new LeerNumeros();
    l.ImportarDNI("59874568p");
}
```

}